# Galois Group of Q(6th roots of unity) over Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to justify that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/6}):\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $C_2$, the cyclic group of order $2$. So far, I've easily shown that the minimal polynomial of $r=e^{2\pi i/6}\ $ is $\ p(x)=x^4+x^2+1$, which has distinct roots $r$ and $r^5$.

From this, one has that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(r):\mathbb{Q})=\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2\}$, where $\sigma_1$ is the unique automorphism that maps $r$ to $r$ (in this case, the identity mapping), and $\sigma_2$ is the unique automorphism that maps $r$ to $r^5$. I'm very rusty in my group theory, so I'm not sure on how to proceed from this point onward. Any help or guidance would be great!

Comment: Any group of order $2$ is isomorphic to $C_2$

Comment: Ah so I guess there's really nothing else to show here then.

Comment: The group is generated by $\sigma_2$; $\quad\sigma_2^2=\sigma_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have that the Galois group is of order $2$, you are basically done showing that it is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $2$, because any group of order $2$ is isomorphic to $C_2$.   (For one thing, any group of prime order is cyclic.)